# How to tell a spigot plugin in the config.yml file "replace me with another string!"

Tags: minecraft

I am developing a spigot plugin for Minecraft ATM, and I want to put something in the config file that tells the program "replace me with another string!" What I mean is something like this:

Appears when someone runs a switch game mode command on another player.

SomeString: 'Hello, (somthing that tells the program replace me with (string)!)'

The reason I want to do this is I want to make it so when you set another player's game mode with a custom command, it says to the person who ran that command "Sets  game mode to .". Please help!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply define a String that acts as the message but allow it to support the game mode parameter is provided. For example;

```
gameModeChangeMessage: 'Sets game mode to %s'
```

Then what you can do is `format` the message if it contains %s, otherwise provide some default message.

```java
String message = getConfig().getString("gameModeChangeMessage");

String messageFormatted = message.contains("%s") ? String.format(message, gameMode) : "A player changed your game mode.";
```

Comment: Thank you! I love Stack Overflow. I always get helpful answers from nice people like you :)

Comment: Thanks! I use spigot frequently so i'm glad I could help!